# PHP/SQL Error: Possible race condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, race-condition

I'm a newbie at programming with AJAX and beginner at PHP programming. I'm not sure why, but when a user clicks an arrow to "Upvote" a post repeatedly and very fast, the PHP login_check decides that the user is no longer logged in. The program works if I click the arrow at a normal speed, but when I rapid fire it gets weird.

PHP code:

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php";
include "functions.php";

sec_session_start();
```

I was wondering if this is a definite case of race conditions and what I could do to prevent it--

AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#upvotearrow").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { }, 500);
    $resdiv=$("#upvotedownvote_resultalert");
    $content=$("#upvotedownvote_resultalert_content");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../secure/process_upvotedownvote.php",
        data: { vote: "upvote", poemid: $("#poemidfield").val() },
        dataType:"HTML"
    })
    .done(function(param) {
        if (param=="true_upvote") {
            $content.html("Upvote registered!");
            $resdiv.css("visibility", "visible");
        }

        else {
            $content.html("Invalid request");
            $resdiv.css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    });         
});

$("#downvotearrow").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { }, 500);
    $resdiv=$("#upvotedownvote_resultalert");
    $content=$("#upvotedownvote_resultalert_content");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", //POST data
        url: "../secure/process_upvotedownvote.php", //Secure upvote/downvote PHP file
        data: { vote: "downvote", poemid: $("#poemidfield").val() }, //Get type of vote and poem_id in URL
        dataType:"HTML" //Set datatype as HTML to send back params to AJAX function
    })
    .done(function(param) { //Param- variable returned by PHP file
        if (param=="true_downvote") {
            $content.html("Downvote registered!");
            $resdiv.css("visibility", "visible");
        }

        else {
            $content.html("Invalid request");
            $resdiv.css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    });
});

    });
```

---

The website with a live demo [can be viewed here.](http://poetryslam.myartsonline.com/poemview.php?poem_id=9)

**TO LOG IN, JUST USE THIS EMAIL: asdf@gmail.com AND THIS PASSWORD: asdf123**

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the race condition (which is likely but shouldn't mess with the session unless it is getting [regenerated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) every time). Anyway, if I were you, I would disable the upvote/downvote button right after the first click.

Comment: Oh crap- the sec_session function does regenerate session Id-- here's a snippet `session_start(); session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.` What should I do now? Rerwite a special sec_session() function just for the upvote/downvote? I don't want to disable the button because I 1) want to allow people to change upvotes->downvotes and vice versa and 2) it would be insecure because they could just alter the javascript

Comment: Well, unless someone better informed than me advices otherwise, I don't think you need to regenerate the session every time. Just make sure you **do regenerate the session upon user login** to prevent session-fixation attacks.
Also, you incur a slight performance penalty (which might be acceptable anyway) if you regenerate every time: generate new random, non-existent token; serialize session contents and store it into new file; delete old file; set new session id through PHPSESSID cookie...

Comment: Dude thank you so much! I searched Stack Overflow for session_regenerate_id security issues and every post I read agreed with you that it wasn't necessary. You saved me from a wild goose chase about race conditions. Thank you again so much!